# Keras model training accuracy dipped drastically while training

Tags: machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am training a neural network based on deep CNNs using Keras and the accuracy while training until the 16th epoch was 90%. It dipped massively to 40% on 17th epoch and then to 3% on the next one and stayed the same until the end of the training. What could have caused that?

This is my model architecture:

```
## input layer
input_layer = Input((S, S, L, 1))

## convolutional layers
conv_layer1 = Conv3D(filters=8, kernel_size=(3, 3, 7), activation='relu', padding = 'same')(input_layer)
conv_layer2 = Conv3D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3, 5), activation='relu', padding = 'same')(conv_layer1)
conv_layer3 = Conv3D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding = 'same')(conv_layer2)
print(conv_layer3._keras_shape)
conv3d_shape = conv_layer3._keras_shape
conv_layer3 = Reshape((conv3d_shape[1], conv3d_shape[2], conv3d_shape[3]*conv3d_shape[4]))(conv_layer3)
conv_layer4 = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu')(conv_layer3)

flatten_layer = Flatten()(conv_layer4)

## fully connected layers
dense_layer1 = Dense(units=256, activation='relu')(flatten_layer)
dense_layer1 = Dropout(0.4)(dense_layer1)
dense_layer2 = Dense(units=128, activation='relu')(dense_layer1)
dense_layer2 = Dropout(0.4)(dense_layer2)
output_layer = Dense(units=output_units, activation='softmax')(dense_layer2)
```

I will add the screenshot of the training:

[training-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqbmY.png)

In this regard, I have two questions:

1. What are the possible reasons for this to take place?
2. I suspect the information could be incorrect. I have set up a checkpoint so the best weights will only be saved. It took about 16 hours to train the model. Is there a way I can still get the training weights of the last epoch i.e. the not best weights while the checkpoint was still in place?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your loss is nan on the 17th epoch
2. It is impossile to recover weights other than by loading from saved weights